# Contracting Around LGPL

Tags: lgpl

A client of mine wants to static link its proprietary commercial work to a library that is licensed under LGPL that is sold by VMime in France.  VMime's website purports to explain that the purchaser does not need to comply with LGPL Section 6 even if statically linking.  From my understanding this is not allowed, to contract around provisions of the LGPL and still license the library under LGPL.

Any thoughts?

Here is the link to their public 'Commercial License' overview: 
https://www.vmime.org/licensing.html#commercial-license

Comment: If VMime is the sole copyright holder of the library they can offer other licenses as well. Their commercial license is apparently similar to the LGPL but allows said linking.

Comment: ^^-- This.  The commercial license is not LGPL.  If your client doesn't want to comply with Section 6, he needs to purchase the commercial license.

Comment: The commercial license they offer provides an agreement that attaches the entirety of LGPL license but purports to exclude Section 6 of the requirements.  I think this is an attempted modification of the LGPL and should not carry with it a reference to LGPL (should not carry preamble, or be called LGPL)  #ModifyGPL

Comment: The commercial license buys the purchaser an exclusion for Section 6.  I actually find that approach very clear and unambiguous.  To be clear, the resulting license is *not LGPL,* nor does it need to be.

Comment: @ShortLegalGroup I'm not sure what your clients reason for wanting static linking is, but note that dynamic linking is *not* a hard & fast requirement of the LGPL -- the only requirement is that *some method for using an alternative version of the library is provided*.  If they are able to provide their application as object files along with a script to relink them to a new version of the LGPL library this would satisfy the license, and may be adequate for their requirements.

Comment: @Jules: You would also have to satisfy the "derivative works" provision of the LGPL.  In order for the linking to qualify both programs as separate works, the non LGPL'd program must communicate at arms length with the LGPL'd portion, and the non-LGPL'd program cannot depend on the LGPL'd portion for a substantial part of its proper functioning.

Comment: @Robert Harvey, agreed the license should not be LGPL, it should be a commercial straight license, however, if the intention is not to license under LGPL (see the Licensing Overview), then you should not attach the original LGPL language with preamble and reference to GNU to the contract, agreed?  (even if the contract purports to exclude Section 6 requirements)

Comment: Does it really matter?  The intent is clear to everyone.  Are you asking whether what they're doing is legal or not, or are you asking how your client should interpret the license?  Be specific; wandering generalities don't help anyone.

Comment: Maybe this is a legal issue related to reference to LGPL and not technical.  If you're signing a contract that purports to attach the GNU LGPL v.3 License language but also has language that purports to exclude provisions of the LGPL.  I believe this is an attempt to modify the LGPL.  If that's the case then you should remove all references to LGPL and GNU in the license agreement and treat it like a straight commercial license.

Comment: The concern is more for down the road when someone is reviewing the licenses that you license your product under and there is reference to LGPL but no downstream compliance with the terms of the LGPL (relying on a contract that indicated you were exempt from the requirements of the attached LGPL).  So I would think good practice would be to not refer to LGPL at ALL in the commercial license because it is not a a true LGPL license even though it borrows many of the provisions (in fact, all but Section 6)

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, and neither is anyone else here.  If your question is whether or not the license is legally enforceable, I suggest you consult a lawyer on that point.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you guys could pass for lawyers

Comment: Only on TV, though, and I don't even play one on TV.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - See LGPL v3 section 4.d.0: all you need to do is provide copy of the LGPL library source (which you should be doing anyway) and the minimum required to relink it, i.e. the object files and any nonstandard library files you're using.  That's not exactly hard in most circumstances.  I used to write software that used LGPL libs on DOS, where this was the only way to do it, and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 6):

The source code repository clarifies the [author](https://github.com/kisli/vmime/blob/master/AUTHORS) and copyright holder of the software.  This author is also the owner of the website that distributes this software according to a dual license principle.

As he is the owner of this software, he can licenses it with the terms and conditions that he wants (as long as he doesn't infringe copyrights of others). The fact that he licenses the software for free since 2003 under the terms of the GPL doesn't prevent him to license it also according to another license schemes.  And the fact that [LGPL](https://opensource.org/licenses/LGPL-3.0) doesn't allow the change of the license document doesn't prevent the copyright holder to grant you an LGPL-based license with exceptions stated elsewhere.

The deal that the author offers is simple and seems very fair:

- you enjoy the software for free but you release your work as open source as well,
- or you pay a license fee and you get license conditions that allow for proprietary software.

So if your customer want closed source he'll have to pay for the commercial license.

***Disclaimer*** This is not legal advice. This is my personal opinion as IT professional.  For legal advice you should contact a lawyer or an authorized  legal expert of your jurisdiction

Answer (score 0):

GPLv3 section 7 begins with the following text:

> “Additional permissions” are terms that supplement the terms of this License by making exceptions from one or more of its conditions. Additional permissions that are applicable to the entire Program shall be treated as though they were included in this License, to the extent that they are valid under applicable law. If additional permissions apply only to part of the Program, that part may be used separately under those permissions, but the entire Program remains governed by this License without regard to the additional permissions.

The Lesser GPL is simply the GPL modified by exceptions under section 7. The first point listed in the VMime link you provide is not an interpretation of the LGPL, but an additional permission, allowing static linking to the VMime code.

The second point is simply a paywall. Copyright holders, and anyone who distributes FLOSS, are permitted to charge as much as they like.

The third point states "You may NOT relicense the VMime code to anyone." If we interpret this as prohibiting you from distributing the software, this effectively creates a "frankenlicense" from the GPL. Luckily, the GPL has you covered in section 7 paragraph 4:

> All other non-permissive additional terms are considered “further restrictions” within the meaning of section 10. If the Program as you received it, or any part of it, contains a notice stating that it is governed by this License along with a term that is a further restriction, you may remove that term.

Of course, I wouldn't advise you to do so unless you're willing to test the GPL in court, but know you have the right to ignore point 3 and redistribute the library code.